# WIth Squeryl (using Lift), how can I make two model classes a subclass of the same class?

Tags: lift, squeryl

Using Lift with Squeryl, how can I make two classes a subclass of the same class?

My classes look like the following:

```
class SubClass1 extends Record[SubClass1] with KeyedRecord[SubClass1] with CreatedUpdated[SubClass1] {

    val id = ...
    val field1a = StringField(...)
    ...

}

class SubClass2 extends Record[SubClass2] with KeyedRecord[SubClass2] with CreatedUpdated[SubClass2] {

    val id = ...
    val field2a = StringField(...)

}
```

I want `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` each to be a child class of some other class, say MyParentClass. So I would think that I would have to do something like this:

```
abstract class MyParentClass extends Record[MyParentClass] with KeyedRecord[MyParentClass] with CreatedUpdated[MyParentClass] {}
```

and then

```
class SubClass1 extends MyParentClass {

    val id = ...
    val field1a = StringField(...)
    ...
}

class SubClass2 extends MyParentClass {

    val id = ...
    val field2a = StringField(...)
    ...
}
```

This gives me errors, such as the fields (`StringField`) etc. not conforming to the right type. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You abstract superclass can't define a concrete type parameter, since it needs to be overriden by the subclasses.  Try:

```
abstract class MyParentClass[A <: MyParentClass] 
  extends Record[A] with KeyedRecord[A] with CreatedUpdated[A]
```

Then:

```
class SubClass extends MyParentClass[SubClass]
```

Comment: Hello Dave, many thanks for responding. I ended up going with a solution that is very similar to yours: 

    `trait MyParentClass[A <: Record[A]] extends Record[A] with KeyedRecord[A] with CreatedUpdated[A] {
      self: A =>
    }
    class MySubClass extends MyParentClass[MySubClass] { ... }`